# How to add SOAP method without param using ckWebServicePlugin

Tags: soap, symfony-1.4

I used this plugin to provide SOAP webservice for application. Overall, it looks good but I stuck when creating a SOAP operation having no params.

Plugin URL: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/ckWebServicePlugin

Answer (score 0):

I added dummy `@param int $var` to get a temporary solution.